# Is it a good idea to make Wordpress theme repository public?

Tags: themes, git, github

I have my custom Wordpress+Woocommerce theme created that I want to show on my github page as a reference.

The theme does not contain any login data. Of course it contains server-side php code that shows how the client page is created. I always tried to structure the logic according to other themes/according to how code inside Woocommerce plugin works.

**Is there a security danger for the site when making the theme source public?**

Comment: Only if you have insecure code in it that a hacker could seen and then know they could exploit. But if you want someone to audit the code for your entire theme, that’s not what this site is for.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a problem, if someone finds a potencial ways to hack into the theme and you use it afterwards on one of your sites.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

- If you're planning to use the theme only for yourself and you're not sure that your code is secure — well, you better keep it from prying eyes
- If you're planning to distribute this theme for free, anyone will be able to access its code, whether you uploaded it on GitHub or not
- If you're planning to sell the theme, then, obviously, it's a bad idea because anyone will be able to download your theme without paying you a penny